# Is it possible to use google as authentication server only without using any API and how

Tags: rest, authentication, google-oauth, google-authentication

I have a C# desktop application that works against a server(play framework 2.5 if it matters)with REST API calls.
I want to authenticate the calls from the client(desktop app) to the server using gmail accounts.
now before displaying the flow, some clarifications:

- the client app is sometimes unattended(I receive the username+password from somewhere else) - meaning displaying a user consent screen is not an option
- I have no interest in any Google APIs! I only want to access my server REST API.
  I only need Google for the authentication stage

### the wanted flow:

In the client:

- get the username and password from the user(as mentioned can be done non interactively)
- authenticate the user against google and get a token
- send a request to the server including the token

In the server:

- "decode" the token back into username
- check if this user is authenticated to do the call and act accordingly

if possible - how would you do it?

Comment: This is perfectly doable (with some questions regarding the unattended Google login). Is there another question in here?

Comment: how would you do it?(also edited the question)

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to setup a new project on the [Google API Manager](https://console.developers.google.com) (that's where that content Guid is coming from below in the meta tag).

On the client side, here's how you can use [Google's Sign-In button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) template to initialize the login & grant of permissions process:

```html
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="29chqvu3ghgtte1.apps.googleusercontent.com">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>

<div id="google-signin-button"
     class="g-signin2"
     data-width="170"
     data-height="30"
     data-onsuccess="onSignIn"
     data-onfailure="onSignInFailure">
</div>
```

```js
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var idToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
}
```

Then you can simply send this idToken to the server/api, from where you can do a GET on Google's endpoint to verify this token `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={0}`. There are of course [numerous other ways](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint) in which you can validate the token (and actually get a handle on it, of course).

This would be the gist of it (excluding the non-interactive user login - keep in mind you'll also need the user to grant permissions).

Comment: But as you said - this will not solve the problem of the non-interactive side which is my biggest concern at the moment